# Auto boot MailHog on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, supervisord, ubuntu-20.04, mailhog

I installed MailHog in my staging environment by following these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get -y install golang-go`
2. `go get github.com/mailhog/MailHog`

In order to manually start the service I do:

1. `cd ~/go/bin`
2. `./MailHog`

Since I'm using Laravel I already have `supervisor` running for workers.
I'm wondering if there is a way to add a new `.conf` file in order to start MailHog.

I tried to follow how Laravel workers are started, but so far no luck

```
[program:mailhog]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=~/go/bin/MailHog
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/var/www/api/storage/logs/mailhog.log
```

I get `mailhog:mailhog_00: ERROR (no such file)` when I try to start supervisor.

I need a way to auto boot MailHog, no matter if I need supervisor or via services.

I'll really appreciate it if you can provide the "recipe" for starting MailHog from the supervisor or by using a service.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figure out how the complete installation/setup should be:

1. Downloading & installation

```
sudo apt-get -y install golang-go
go get github.com/mailhog/MailHog
```

2. Copy Mailhog to bin directory

```
sudo cp ~/go/bin/MailHog /usr/local/bin/MailHog
```

3. Create MailHog service

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/mailhog.service <<EOL
[Unit]
Description=MailHog
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/MailHog > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOL
```

Note: Change the `User=ubuntu` to your `username`.

4. Check status service is loaded successfully.

```
sudo systemctl status mailhog
```

Output

```
mailhog.service - MailHog
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mailhog.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

5. Start service

```
sudo systemctl enable mailhog
```

6. Reboot system and visit http://yourdomain.com:8025/

Comment: did all the steps, all good, mailhog runs, however, visiting :8025 does not work, never loading

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a supervisor, you can use Linux `systemd` to create a startup application.

systemd is the standard system and service manager in modern Linux. It is responsible for executing and managing programs during Linux startup

before that add mailhog to your system path variable to call it only by name

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/YOUR-USERNAME/go/bin/MailHog`

`sudo systemctl enable mailhog`

or if you are using any desktop environment , you can follow this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: sudo systemctl enable mailhog
Failed to enable unit: Unit file mailhog.service does not exist.